# How do you adjust the size of Input and Output Buffers used by Android MediaCodec?

Tags: java, android, audio, signal-processing, codec

I am trying to process audio signal data while streaming at the same time, using Android AudioTrack/MediaCodec APIs.

The audio data must be cut into frames(windows) of certain sizes (1024 in my case) before I do any further analysis, which is why I was trying to change the size of input and output buffers going into the MediaCodec so that they are of the same size as, or multiples of the frame sizes.

```
readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);
writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);
```

Code above allocates byte buffers of capacity 2048 to *readBuffer* and *writeBuffer*, as I verified by logging *readBuffer.capacity()*.

However, these two lines of code seem to dequeue an input buffer with a much larger capacity (*readBuffer.capacity()*: 196608):

```
inputBufIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(1000);
readBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);
```

I have three questions:

1. How is the size of the result buffer of *codec.getInputBuffer()* determined? Does it depend on the media format used?
2. As described above, is it correct to match the buffer size with  the frame size if I want to stream and analyze the audio data simultaneously?
3. How would you resize the input and output buffers that go through the MediaCodec?